# Algebraic Identities - Factor and expand

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

Given that: $$x^2 - xy + y^2 = 2$$
$$w^2 + wz + z^2 = 2$$
$$wz + 4 = xy$$

Evaluate $$\sqrt[5]{2(x^2z^2 + x^2y^2+4z^2)}$$

I tried to apply the *Sophie Germain identity* in the last expression, but failed.
So, in order to get rid of $w$, I've manipulated those equations and didn't came to a conclusion so far. Can you help me with this seemingly simple algebra problem?

Comment: I also found it strange when I first analyzed the problem, but maybe $w$ doesn't matter to the numerical value of the expression. I'll plug-in some values to confirm it.
Otherwise, we should simplify the expression, factoring it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two equations can be expressed as:-

$$(x-y)^2+xy=2
\\(w+z)^2-wz=2$$
Summing these, and using the third equation, we have
$$(x-y)^2=-(w+z)^2$$ 
which can only hold true if $x=y$ and $w=-z$, assuming all numbers are real.

This simply leads to $x^2=y^2=w^2=z^2=2$, so the result of your expression is $$\sqrt[5]{2(4+4+8)}=2$$